# Multiple users and households in Sims 3

Tags: the-sims-3

Can someone explain the sims 3 households for me?

So my fiancee created a sim and played with it in bridgeport. I then started a new game and created a new sim. We both want to marry eventually but yeah i keep explaining to her that this is a new iteration of sims(she says that in sims 2 you could do that).

SO basically we'll both be in different worlds but with the same characters, right? So if i get married in MY save file, she won't(unlike in sims 2 where you can "take control" of any other sims that are in the same neighborhood as yours)

Am I correct or is there a way? Come to think of it, I dont think thats possible with different save files as we have different states of play and progress and merging them will be a nightmare...right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike in the Sims 2, each save file exists in its own, separate universe.

In the Sims 2, time did not pass for sims you weren't playing. However, in the Sims 3, the "Story Progression" means that no matter which household you play, time will pass for *all* families in the neighborhood.

The one thing that *is* shared between neighborhoods is the Family bins -- that is to say, both you and your fiancee should have each other's sim in their neighborhood bin. If you then move this sim into the neighborhood (even if you don't change the active household), you will be able to find, meet, seduce, and eventually marry each other's sim.

However, because you have separate save files, marrying in one neighborhood won't simultaneously marry the sims in the second neighborhood.

It *is* possible to simply play multiple active families in the same neighborhood, but since every household ages at the same rate in The Sims 3, this will probably not be a preferable way to play (not to mention losing wants every time you switch active households).

Comment: of course there are some thigss you can do to mitigate some of the "negative" aspects that @Raven mentioned regarding each of you having a sim in the same neighborhood. you can turn off the aforementioned Story Mode, which will prevent the non-active family sims from progressing in life (job promotions, marriage, etc). you can also turn off aging, so that no one will grow older. changing these two options, however, will make for a very static neighborhood.

Comment: hmm thanks for the tips! we usually turn off aging as we like to play without a limit, but story progression is still fun. we've settled with losing wants every time we switch for now though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to marry your sim to your fiancee's sim, you can click on **Edit Town**, there you'll see family bin, select your fiancee's sim, move a copy to your sim's town. That way you can have her in your own town(world), your sim can look her up using **Online Dating** on computer, and increase the relationship value with her until they both agree to marry.